# Updating to newest GCC/G++

Tags: raspbian, gcc

After updating my Raspbian Pi 4B through `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`, I noticed that it has quite old GCC/G++ version `8.3.0` while there exists already release of `11.2`.

Can anyone suggest how can I install a newer one? Preferably through some apt server that has package with recent version.

In Google I see that there exists [such tutorial](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/12/08/raspberry-pi-raspbian-install-gcc-compile-cpp-17-programs/) that installs GCC version 10. It is also an option, but yet APT-based solution would be more comfortable for me if possible.

Also this tutorial is about v10, but there exists 11.2. So maybe anyone can suggest were to get v11.2 compiled for CPU compatible with Pi 4B.

Just for information my `uname -a` shows:

```
Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ #1333 SMP Mon Aug 10 16:51:40 BST 2020 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

and `lsb_release -d` shows:

```
Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
```

My distro seems to be marked as `oldstable` right now that I can see when doing `apt search gcc`, it shows `gcc/oldstable,now 4:8.3.0-1+rpi2 armhf [installed]` (notice `oldstable` word).

Also if my Raspbian version is too old, and newer version contains more updated GCC, then can anyone suggest shell commands how to upgrade my distro to newest possible? Without re-imagining whole flash from scratch.

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye comes with GCC 10.2.1 - which is what the latest Debian comes with - it's not 11, but it's not 8 either :p - there was a question here about upgrading buster to bullseye - seems to have been deleted though - there is a guide on raspberry pi forums - it worked for me on 4 out of 5 pi's - so that's an 80 percent success rate

Comment: @Bravo If you'll find these distro-upgrade instructions somewhere later, please post a link here.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your system to Bullseye, then you'll get GCC 10.2. In order to upgrade, replace `buster` with `bullseye` in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and run

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
 apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You can't just install packages from random repositories: packages depend on one another, that's why you need `dpkg/apt`, and not just `zip` or whatever archiver you might use. If you absolutely need the latest `gcc`, you'll have to install it from sources or create a `chroot` jail for a different OS, provided that OS is compatible with the Raspbian kernel, and install packages for that OS.

Comment: Thanks! Up-Voted. Can you tell if `apt dist-upgrade` command is totally enough to upgrade to `Bullseye` from `Buster`? Nothing else is needed, just one command and I get new distro?

Comment: After `dist-uprade` what I'll see in `lsb_release -d`? Now I see `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)`. Will I see Bullseye when calling `lsb_release -d` after doing `dist-upgrade`? Or dist-upgrade just updates only APTs?

Comment: BTW, what's the most recent distro? Is Bullseye the newest possible? Is it Stable or UnStable? What will be the codename of most unstable but most newest distro?

Comment: I've followed this but the gcc is still `gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110`. I was hoping for a version 11!